# how can I stop my php form resubmitting input after page refresh

Tags: php

```
 <?php

$connection = mysqli_connect("host", "username", "password")
or die("Couldn't connect to the server"); //no issue 

$db = mysqli_select_db($connection, "dbname")
or die("Couldn't select database"); //no issue
$sql = "INSERT INTO vendor-tbl(company_name, industry, details, website, data_type, start_date) VALUES ('".$_POST['company_name']."','".$_POST['industry']."','".$_POST['details']."','".$_POST['website']."','".$_POST['data_type']."','".$_POST['start_date']."')";

// mysqli_query(($connection,$sql);
 if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
} 

$conn->close(); //closes the connection       
?>      
<form autocomplete="on" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post" role="form">

<label id="company_name">Company Name:</label><br/>
<input type="text" name="company_name" id="company_name" autocomplete='organization'><br/>

<label id="industry">Industry:</label><br/>
<input type="text" name="industry" id="industry" autocomplete='industry'><br/>

<label id="details">Details:</label><br/>
<input type="text" name="details" id="details" autocomplete='details'><br/>

<label id="website">Website:</label><br/>
<input type="text" name="website" id="website" autocomplete='website'><br/>

<label id="data_type">Data Type:</label><br/>
<input type="text" name="data_type" id="data_type" autocomplete='datatype'><br/>

<label id="start_date">Start Date:</label><br/>
<input type="text" name="start_date" id="start_date" autocomplete='startdate'><br/>

<button id="submitButton" value="submit" name="submit">Submit</button><br/>


</form>
```

When I refresh my form after just submitting data, it seems to add that data into phpmyadmin twice, and if I reload the form another time(blank form) it adds the data a third time etc. Is there any way of preventing this without using session variables?
I'm very inexperienced with php but I have tried using session variables but I didn't seem to get it working.

Comment: do you press F5? if yes, of course it will ask for resubmitting your form

Comment: Yes, but how do I stop a refresh causing a resubmit of what was previously entered?

Comment: why there is a `;` besides `if(isset($_POST['name']))`? I think this causes your problem.

Comment: sorry, that was a mistake, I removed it, but it doesn't cause the problem

Comment: first load it will insert empty values then after submit it will insert values you inputted? which why you think it resubmitting

Comment: correct, if first load it inserts empty values and then when you input , submit, reload it resubmits that last values inputtd

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is a "post/redirect/get", for which you use an 303. This way you do a post, and then are 'forced' to do a get. When you f5, you reload that get and so not your post..

see:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_303

Answer (score -1):

Use `isset()` to check if the button was entered

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     $connection = mysqli_connect("host", "username", "password")
or die("Couldn't connect to the server"); //no issue 

$db = mysqli_select_db($connection, "dbname")
or die("Couldn't select database"); //no issue
$sql = "INSERT INTO vendor-tbl(company_name, industry, details, website, data_type, 
start_date) VALUES ('".$_POST['company_name']."','".$_POST['industry']."','".$_POST['details']."','".$_POST['website']."','".$_POST['data_type']."','".$_POST['start_date']."')";

// mysqli_query(($connection,$sql);
 if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
     echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
  } 
}
```

Comment: It still resubmits after that

Comment: change `action="#"` @kjjjkjjj

Answer (score -1):

Solution:

```
<?php
 if($_POST){
$connection = mysqli_connect("host", "username", "password")
or die("Couldn't connect to the server"); //no issue 

$db = mysqli_select_db($connection, "dbname")
or die("Couldn't select database"); //no issue
$sql = "INSERT INTO vendor-tbl(company_name, industry, details, website, data_type, start_date) VALUES ('".$_POST['company_name']."','".$_POST['industry']."','".$_POST['details']."','".$_POST['website']."','".$_POST['data_type']."','".$_POST['start_date']."')";
// mysqli_query(($connection,$sql);
 if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;

} 
$conn->close(); //closes the connection       
Header("Location: " . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
 }

?>
```